# upgrading Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS to 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I have several AWS ec2 instances that I want to upgrade.
(i did it from 16.04 to 18.04 and now I want to go to 20.04)

I use them only for apache/nginx, php, wordpress sites and docker, so I dont touch other system configuration files.

during system upgrade with:

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade

it asks me for some changes to different files:

- A new version (/tmp/grub.QCD0kA1oxG) of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available
- A new version (/tmp/fileNDIUCr) of configuration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config is available
- A new version (/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades.ucftmp) of configuration file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades is available

although I didnt touched this files, is it possible that maybe being in AWS to have some things changed in sshd for example to allow me to connect to the instance?

I dont have a lot of clues about system configurations, what should be the default approach to these?
keep the current version or upgrade to maintainers version? or some other option?

Comment: The default is generally to keep the old version. However personally I prefer the other option: First I check the differences and try to incorporate any updates I have done on the old version, to the new version. You will find that most differences are small and in the comments. It is worth spending some time to understand them.

Comment: I tried to look at the differences but most of them I dont understand. I think they are just way on how the system handles different things. I asked to make sure I dont mess something up. When I moved with the upgrade to 20.04.2 LTS it made me install also some 'snap lxd' package which i am not sure it was needed though..